# not working on firebase but work on local host

Tags: node.js, firebase, localhost, firebase-hosting

On my local host  directory '/form' is working, page is rendering. 
But when I deploy on firebase it's given me 404. 
If I change 404 file itself, I can see a changes. I clear a cache, restart nothing help.

Please advice whats wrong.

Here is backend code

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
     res.sendFile('/index.html');
 });

 app.get('/form', function(req,res){
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/form.html'));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happend with me too, basically the firebase changing the "backend url" to localhost or just ignoring it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).